# The new /review is showing me stuff I've already reviewed

Tags: discussion, review

What's the status of the [new review section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community) that is being tested (originally [documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks))?

When going into it today my all time edit stats had been reset to zero, and it is showing me a bunch of questions/answers that I have already reviewed in the past.

What is going on? Are there not enough people using it so votes are decaying? Are the questions/answers being shown ever going to get actioned as a result of these reviews, or are they test fodder?

Regardless of what happens to the items I review, do not reset my stats, even if the feature is in alpha! You guys (SO devs) know how people moan when you mess with their numbers! Showing me stuff I've already reviewed in the past is also not a good way to keep me coming back to use the feature (for the record I think the feature has merit).

Now that I've had a whinge, can you give us an update on the feature?

(Rather than dredge up an old question and/or add a post to the end of that question where it might not get seen I decided to post this as a new question - keeping it front and centre may help get more people trialling it).

Comment: I experienced this problem today.