# I see the posts I review more than once

Tags: support, review

I noticed that, when I review a low quality post, and I select "Recommend Deletion," I see the same post after few hours, when I restart reviewing low quality posts. Each time I restart reviewing posts, I click on the review link I see on the top of the page, and I click on the "Low Quality Posts" link I see on that page.

Am I supposed to see the same post twice? If I select "Recommend Deletion," I still think it should be deleted the second time I see it.
Reviewing low quality posts should be done once per post. Maybe it makes sense to show the same post when I select "Not Sure," but in that case it would make more sense to move the post at the bottom, when I review again low quality posts. (This would mean to record for which posts I selected "Not Sure"; I am not suggesting it should be done, as I understand it is not worth doing it.)

Comment: If this is the review feature that's in beta, then this is partially a dupe (it's been doing this for some time): [The new /review is showing me stuff I've already reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138240/the-new-review-is-showing-me-stuff-ive-already-reviewed)

Comment: A combination of caching and the birthday paradox :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time, our review-invalidation logic was overzealous and not very user-friendly:

If many reviews were performed by the same user in a short period of time (as was the case for you), a fraction of them were invalidated. Then, those same tasks were given to you again, since you were no longer considered to have reviewed them.

This is fixed now: if a review would be invalidated, the buttons are instead temporarily disabled on the client, making it much more difficult to submit a review too fast.

Comment: It seemed strange that one could make so much reviews in few time, but I have would not have understood that would cause me to see the already reviewed posts. Thank you for your answer.