# Received a question in the close vote review queue that I had already voted to close

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)
>   [I see the posts I review more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139767/i-see-the-posts-i-review-more-than-once)

Today, while using the "Close Votes" task in the new [review tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/review) on Stack Overflow, I [was presented](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/198777) with a [(book recommendation) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920085/books-for-ui-development-in-xna-4-0) that I could not vote to close. It turns out, I had previously voted to close that question while browsing questions on the site (not from /review), and the close vote has since expired.

I believe this new close vote queue already avoids showing me questions where I have an *active* close vote; could the existence of *expired* close votes be added to that filter (since I still cannot really act on the post's need for closure anymore)?

<sub>I've marked this as a bug, rather than a feature request, since it seems like this is just an oversight.</sub>

Comment: How come the possible duplicate link got removed??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd kiamlaluno realized his close vote was a mistake (because it's not a duplicate of that question), so he removed the auto-comment.

Comment: Hmm.. don't think this should be possible as the close vote is still there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You can still see the close vote count, though.  And you can navigate through the close vote menu to see what the target question was.

Comment: True, but it's still confusing. [Asked to fix this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142838/dont-allow-the-user-to-delete-his-own-possible-duplicate-auto-comment) now.. :)

Comment: Good catch, we missed this case. Fixing..

Comment: @razlebe That's about the old review system, and it's a different problem.  That's seeing the same post in /review more than once, this is seeing a post in /review for the first time, but I can't act on it because I voted to close it in the past *outside* of /review.  Make sense?

Comment: Also, that was marked as fixed in January, and Emmett just fixed this a few days ago o_O

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yes, you're right. Apologies.

Comment: @razlebe No worries.  You're the third person to mistakenly vote-to-close this question, so I'm starting to think ***I*** was unclear somehow =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed.

Now, if you have *ever* cast a close or delete vote, you shouldn't see that post in the close vote review queue.