# Do not show posts in the reopen queue to those who closed them if there haven't been any edits

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should a question that I voted to close, appear in my “Reopen” queue if it has not been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151665/should-a-question-that-i-voted-to-close-appear-in-my-reopen-queue-if-it-has-n)

Just now, on MSO, I was shown an entry in the reopen queue of a post which I had just closed. The post had zero edits.

This means that the closing of the post is a controversial issue (instead of the usual case--the closing of the post is outdated given the recent edits). In such cases, the user who closed the post is probably going to hit <kbd>Leave Closed</kbd>, removing it from the queue. IMO, this leads to an unbalanced state -- if the VTCers suppress the post from appearing in the reopen queue (maybe not intentionally, but that's what may happen). This is in line with the current system of "if you've VTCd a post once, you can't do it again for the same post".

What I propose is that, *if a post has not been improved* since it was closed(or since the user in question VTCd it), then it should not show up in the reopen queue for the close users. Even better, *do* show it up in the reopen queue, but make the "leave closed" button do nothing for that user (as in, it counts as a "skip"). Another idea would be to grey out the "leave closed" button with a note "since you have already voted to close this post, you may not vote to leave closed. Read the post again, comment on the closing if you feel like it. If you feel that it should be reopened, vote to reopen, otherwise skip." -- this will encourage VTCers to take a closer look.

Comment: @benisuqbackwards: true, didn't see that. But yeah, here I've added a "middle ground" proposal which I like better (and the answers there don't apply to it, because the middle ground promotes self-review but doesn't allow conflict).