# Reviewing one's own close votes

Tags: discussion, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

When a post comes up for reopen review, for instance, after a post-close edit, it is possible for reviewers to be asked to judge their own close votes.  For example, in this review (which I guess not many can see)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/14888

on this tex.sx question:

[How to export high quality charts from excel to import in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101182/how-to-export-high-quality-charts-from-excel-to-import-in-latex)

two of the reviewers were among the close voters.

I'm not sure what I think about this.  Is there a conflict of interest here, or is it good to have this kind of continued input in the review process?

Comment: Actually, I can see that review and the names attached to the actions, and I'm not even logged in there.

Answer (score 6):

See also: [Should a question that I voted to close, appear in my "Reopen" queue if it has not been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151665/should-a-question-that-i-voted-to-close-appear-in-my-reopen-queue-if-it-has-n)

The *only* time you see a post that you've closed in the reopening queue is when an edit has been made.

Keeping that in mind, I see no issue here. Closing is *meant* to be temporary. When you VTC a salvageable post, you're saying "fix it, we'll reopen it". Which means that there's no issue with having the close-voters reviewing the same post. In fact, this is *desirable*, since you are better acquainted with the question.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that qn.  So this is by design.

Comment: @CharlesStewart: yep

Comment: @Charles Definitely; I just voted to reopen a question I had voted to close, myself. Do it occasionally. (And with pleasure!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: With _pleasure_? _tsk_ you'll find it hard to gain acceptance amongst us mods if/when you get elected if you reopen stuff with pleasure. You've got to take pleasure in closing ALL THE QUESTIONS(.jpg). Everyone knows that. :P

Comment: Hehe... busted! October surprise?

Comment: Errr, for those not aware, October Surprise refers to a big, election-altering story coming out just before an election. (US elections are held early November)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yeah, I know :)