# Seeing my own edit in the reopen queue

Tags: discussion, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

I just [edited a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/197583/revisions) (revision 3). Then I decided to go review something, so I entered the reopen review queue. I somehow [reviewed the question I just edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18257).

Shouldn't a question not show up in the review queue to the one who edited it? This could be gamed - just edit a random closed question, review it as "leave closed" in the reopen queue, and get a free "reopen queue" review point (counting towards the Steward badge).

<sub>[vaguely related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151665/180276)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why it shouldn't? Think of it as a reminder.

> Hey, you edited this question. Did you want to vote to reopen it, too?

Voting to reopen a question after editing it is a completely normal behavior. In fact, the Reopen Votes queue even has an **Edit & Reopen** button for each item. So I don't see why it shouldn't show you a question just because you've edited it.

Comment: Yes, but this could be gamed. Edit closed questions, then immediately review them, for free reopen points.

Comment: *shrugs* I only really see a problem with that behavior if they're minor edits that don't really do anything. But then again, there are *tons* of random Reopen Votes items where the only difference is minor grammar changes. You'd have to be pretty dedicated to game it this way, because it wouldn't even pop into the queue until *at least* 15 minutes after your edit.

Comment: "reopen points", @Doorknob?

Comment: @Shog9 You know, for the Steward badge and such

Comment: That's gotta be one of the more difficult ways of gaming a badge I've heard. If you manage to pull it off *without* making a bunch of worthless edits, more power to you @Doorknob.

Comment: @Shog9 Can I game the First Posts queue by creating duplicate accounts that post questions that will inevitably pop up in that queue?

Comment: Are they good questions? Strictly-speaking, no, because you'd have to violate the "no touching" rule for duplicate accounts.

Comment: @Shog9 Alright, I guess that makes sense. Reopen queue usually gets less questions anyway, but I suppose it still would be incredibly tedious. Will accept this answer when SO lets me

Answer (score 8):

Why not?

Your options are:

- Leave Closed (you don't think your edit fixed the problems)
- Edit and Reopen (well, you've already done at least one of these, but you could do it again)
- Reopen (if you'd already voted to reopen, you wouldn't be given the review task, so here's your chance to do it if you think it makes sense)
- Skip (if you really don't have a strong opinion on the post you edited, this is always an option)

Per my comments in parentheses, all of these are possible and make sense in this context.