# Operation of reopen queue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I have a misunderstanding of the operation of the reopen queue, but it's in reference to the following question on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). I'm posting here because presumably it would apply across the SE network:

[A few OPAMP questions I have a hard time finding the answers to](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109349/a-few-opamp-questions-i-have-a-hard-time-finding-the-answers-to)

As of now it was closed 23 hours ago as being too broad but was edited around 6 hours to include proper schematics. While I don't think it should be reopened because it is still three questions rolled into one it hasn't appeared on the reopen queue for me and viewing from a private browser window shows that queue as empty. The last review on the queue was 9 hours ago for a different question.

I've seen this a few times before and wondered if I'm missing something obvious or if there's some sort of gremlin?

Comment: A post doesn't have to appear in the queue for people to vote to reopen. Visiting the post *directly* also lets you vote.

Comment: Yes realise that, but the queue brings extra attention so wondering why it didn't appear for me. It often does and prompts me to reopen a question after its been improved.

Comment: You might have discovered a bug, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151665/should-a-question-that-i-voted-to-close-appear-in-my-reopen-queue-if-it-has-n) it should indeed show for you in the reopen queue. Since then many things changed so maybe that fix was overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post doesn't *have* to appear in the queue for people to vote to reopen. Visiting the post *directly* also lets you vote.

Moreover, if enough people voted to *leave it closed* then it'd be booted from the queue. I see you don't have 10k yet on EE, so you cannot yet review other people's actions in that queue.

If it *was* booted from the queue, it was booted before you ever got to see it there.

Comment: Just to clarify, so a few 10k users (or presumably one mod) can dismiss a reopen vote straight from the question? In this case I don't think it happened from the queue and I missed it, because the last reopen action was a lot longer ago, remembering smaller sites like EE only get a few a day.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. 10k users can *see the review history*. A few 3k+ users, those with reopen privileges, can vote to 'leave closed' *in the review queue* and it'll be removed from the queue. Since you don't yet have 10k you cannot verify this (and neither can I).

Comment: Because you don't yet have 10k, all you see on the history tab are your own reviews. This post won't be on there because you didn't review it and you don't have enough rep to see the actions of others listed there.

Comment: I was just reminded of this question when someone upvoted it, now I have 10k there I can see you were right and a diamond mod fairly quickly voted to leave it closed which is why I never saw it on the queue.