# Same question goes through close review queue twice, is that good or bad?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Recently stumbled upon a question that has been put into close votes queue **twice**:

1. [First round](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/37423) (3:1 Leave Open)
2. [Second round](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/38000) (4:1 Close)

As far as I can tell, question entered the queue second time after *first round* votes on it [expired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120896/165773) and someone else cast a new vote.

Is it good or bad that question may hit the close votes review queue more than once?

<sub>Please note this question is not a complaint about review item shown to someone more than once, because this is not what happened, I just discovered above reviews by occasion.</sub>

---

My search at MSO so far led only to brief and very generic explanation of the queue purpose in [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review/info):

> view and act on posts by other users that **the system thinks may need attention**.

Close votes (and probably reopen) queue being "reentrant" in the way described above apparently is intended to speed-up the process of making a close / leave open decision.

For the *first round* reviews, I believe it is commonly agreed to be a good thing, but I have not seen an explanation for why such a decision speed up is considered good for next round(s) of voting.

---

My current take is that this is rather a *good* thing.

Due to the fact that [queue doesn't show to reviewer questions they already voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142439/165773), it helps to faster bring attention of more reviewers, which in theory leads to more thoroughly considered decisions.

But there may be also considerations against this that I just somehow missed.

<sub>For the sake of completeness, "reentrant queue" also probably speeds up "close / reopen wars". But I am neither convinced that this would be an ultimately bad thing, nor have seen this widespread enough to warrant concerns.</sub>