# Why isn't there a wait for suggested edits approval clicks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Seem that if I try and upvote more than one comment too fast I get the warning about having to wait five seconds, or if I leave a comment I have to wait fifteen seconds between them. Why doesn't the suggested edits queue put a similar wait on clicking through on "approve" clicks? Looks like you can easily just click away (intentionally or accidentally) and rapidly approve suggested edits without any kind of limit.

Comment: I probably won't give up on the suggested edit queue, but I've been tempted. Recently, what a garbage heap of trivial or destructive, rapidly-approved edits.

Answer (score 1):

There should be already a delay when reviewing suggested edits too fast. In [I see the posts I review more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139767/i-see-the-posts-i-review-more-than-once), one of the developers says:

> If many reviews were performed by the same user in a short period of time (as was the case for you), a fraction of them were invalidated. Then, those same tasks were given to you again, since you were no longer considered to have reviewed them.
>
> This is fixed now: if a review would be invalidated, **the buttons are instead temporarily disabled on the client**, making it much more difficult to submit a review too fast.

There isn't a dialog box that appears when you click on the buttons too quickly, but the buttons are enabled with a delay.

When I review posts, the delay is noticeable. I cannot click any of the buttons too quickly. The delay is less than 5 seconds, and it is probably enough for avoiding I review too much posts (basing on the criteria they used for "too much reviewed posts").

Comment: I understand what you're saying but if there really is a delay (and not just the AJAX delay) then I don't think it's long enough. It's still very easy to blast through and approve edits whereas, for example, if you try and upvote comments too fast you get the orange box with the five second warning.

Comment: With comments it is different. The 5 seconds delay between actions on comments are strictly forced for a different reason, which [Jeff Atwood explained with "rate limiting requires this"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14427/140449).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is...?

When I move from one review to the next, the option buttons at the top of the screen are greyed out briefly before I am actually able to click them.

Comment: That's just the delay imposed by the AJAX request. You can still click  like a madman on approve and move onto the next question. No timer imposed wait like with comments.

Comment: @j08691 Ah. My mistake, I suppose. I haven't tried to speed-click through the reviews, myself. :-)