# Why do I keep getting questions back in the new review system?

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The new /review is showing me stuff I've already reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138240/the-new-review-is-showing-me-stuff-ive-already-reviewed)
>   [I see the posts I review more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139767/i-see-the-posts-i-review-more-than-once)

I sometimes notice that I get the same questions 2,3 times shown again after I already reviewed it. Why is this? Bug?

Comment: What have you been clicking when you reviewed it... Not Sure?

Comment: Looks good or recommend deletion

Comment: also: [The new /review is showing me stuff I've already reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138240/the-new-review-is-showing-me-stuff-ive-already-reviewed)